# Error:- Program to Split the Middle term using Quadratic Equation

Tags: c++

I coded a Program that split the middle term of a quadratic and make it easy for student to solve
complex equation in easy but when I tried to make both number positive by multiplying them "(-1)" it just
does not change anything or it is not giving desired output. Full Code is include that code is on Line 43-45;It will great if you help; Thank You;

```
// Program to Split the Middle term using Quadratic Equation

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void quadratic_formula(int a,int b, int c){//standard form of a quadratic equation is
// ax^2+bx+c. so I hope these argument are now understandable lets continue
// quadratic formula is "-b +/- under root "b^2 - 4ac / 2a

double return_value_01, return_value_02;

double denominator=2*a;

double bracket_value=b*b - 4*a*c;

// an sqrt of a negative number is not allowed that why it is printing 'nan' or "not a number"
// so we will check if a number is negative and convert it if it is found neg.

try{
    if(bracket_value < 0){
        throw bracket_value;
    }
}
catch(int bracket_value){
    bracket_value * (-1);
}

return_value_01=b*(-1)/denominator + sqrt(bracket_value)/denominator;

return_value_02=b*(-1)/denominator - sqrt(bracket_value)/denominator;

 // if the value of 'a' is other than 1 then we have to multiply the value by 
    // that number so that middle term can we obtained;

    if (a != 1 ){
        return_value_01*=a;
        return_value_02*=a; 
    }    

    // making both numbers positive and showing relation to complete the solution
    // this will provide an easy solution to the user without any symbol confusion

    if (return_value_02 < 0){
        return_value_02 * (-1);
    }
    else if(return_value_01 < 0){
        return_value_01 * (-1);
    }


//printing stuff
cout << "First Number: " << return_value_01 << endl
<< "Second Number: " << return_value_02 << endl; 

// notifying a user of a possible relation between both numbers for the easy solution.

if (return_value_01 - return_value_02 == b){
    cout << "Relation Between Them is Negative" << " First Number - Second Number" << endl;
}

else if (return_value_01 + return_value_02 == b){
    cout << "Relation Between Them is Positive" << " First Number + Second Number" << endl;
}

else if (return_value_02 - return_value_01 == b){
    cout << "Relation Between Them is Negative" << " Second Number - First Number" << endl;
}

else if (return_value_02 + return_value_01 == b){
    cout << "Relation Between Them is Positive." << " Second Number + First Number" << endl;
}

}

int main(){
    quadratic_formula(2,3,-90);
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use a try-catch block to do the equivalent of `bracket_value = std::abs(bracket_value)`? Btw, that's also your error, read about variable shadowing.

Comment: Because I learned it few days ago so I really wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
    if(bracket_value < 0){
        throw bracket_value;
    }
}
catch(double &bracket_value){
    bracket_value *= (-1);
}
```

You need to use *= or x = x * (-1);

Similarly when you are checking

```
if (return_value_02 < 0){
    return_value_02 * (-1);
}
else if(return_value_01 < 0){
    return_value_01 * (-1);
}
```

You need to use *= rather than just * :

```
if (return_value_02 < 0){
    return_value_02 *= (-1);
}
else if(return_value_01 < 0){
    return_value_01 *= (-1);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not a try block but at Line 45. It is not executing. By the way, Try and Catch are working well. I know there is not a need to use Try and Catch but I wanted to try.

Comment: In your question you state issue it with flipping the signs

Comment: ya but look at line 45(as it in my VS Code) there is code that can Change the sign of value if any of them are negative, that part! that part is not giving result

Comment: thank you. It is now solved. I think I forgot a very basic rule. BTW thank you